# How to get image URL from media_sideload_image?

Tags: images, urls, attachments

I upload external images for media library using following way.

```
$new_image_url = media_sideload_image($new_url, $post_ID, $title);
```

This method return complete img src tag or 'src' for the image URL.

I need to get image URL from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the *fourth* input parameter (available in 4.2+):

```
@param string $return  
       Optional. Accepts 'html' (image tag html) or 'src' (URL). Default 'html'.
```

So change your code snippet to:

```
$new_image_url = media_sideload_image($new_url, $post_ID, $title, $src = 'src' );
```

to get the `src` instead of the default `html`.

Note that the output might also be an `WP_Error` object for errors, so you might add a check for that.